# List all movies with specific genres and countries

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database with information about movies. In my application I have many filters for those movies. For example, user can select some genres and countries and application should return all movies with those genres and countries.

I wrote some SQL and it works. Is there better solution for my problem?

```
SELECT m.*
FROM movies m
WHERE m.id IN (
  SELECT groupped_movies.id
  FROM (
         SELECT m.id,
                array_agg(mc.country_code) country_codes,
                array_agg(mg.genre_id)     genre_ids
         FROM movies m
                LEFT JOIN movie_countries mc on m.id = mc.movie_id
                LEFT JOIN movie_genres mg on m.id = mg.movie_id
         GROUP BY m.id
       ) groupped_movies
   WHERE groupped_movies.country_codes @> ARRAY ['ru', 'ja'] AND groupped_movies.genre_ids @> ARRAY [1, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code might work fine in Postgres.  But I would think of something more like this:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM movies m 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT mc.movie_id
              FROM movie_countries mc
              WHERE m.id = mc.movie_id AND
                    mc.country_code IN ('ru', 'ja')
              GROUP BY mc.movie_id
              HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
             ) AND
      EXISTS (SELECT mg.movie_id
              FROM movie_genres mg
              WHERE m.id = mg.movie_id AND
                    mc.country_code IN (1, 2, 3)
              GROUP BY mc.movie_id
              HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
             )
```

At the very least, this avoids the Cartesian product so it should have better performance.